# Issue with GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am working with Apollo GraphQL.

I have table with three  records and queried from the same with graphQL as flows

Query

```
query getAuthors($lastName: String){
  author(lastName:$lastName){
    id
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

Query variable

```
{
  "lastName": "Smith"
}
```

Result

```
{
  "data": {
    "author": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "Smith"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But if I  supply query variable as null, I am getting the  response as follows (Seems like fetching all records )

Query variable

```
{
  "lastName": null
}
```

Result

```
{
  "data": {
    "author": [ {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "Smith"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Maria",
        "lastName": "Garcia"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Maria",
        "lastName": "Rodriguez"
      }]
  }
}
```

I am confusing that why I am getting all records even if I pass null value for lastName

Comment: If you want to have an error message you could add `$lastName: String!`. If it should be nullable then please provide the query resolver

Comment: const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    author(_, args) {
console.log(args);
      return Author.findAll({ where: args });
    },